# Unable to execute bash scripts from within fish-shell

Tags: bash, path, fish

I have a collection of bash scripts that I have added to the `PATH` so that I can execute them from anywhere.

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/<path>/<to>/<scripts>
```

so along with

```
./<path>/<to>/<scripts>/mt-sync-github-projects
```

I can use

```
mt-sync-github-projects
```

This all works as expected from bash but not from within fish-shell. I have to call bash and pass the script path as an argument, and any other arguments while executing:

```
bash ./<path>/<to>/<scripts>/mt-sync-github-projects <other-arguments-if-at-all>
```

I have verified that even though I did not add the location to fish's `PATH` explicitly, it does show me the right value for `PATH` using `echo $PATH` and the scripts have a shebang specifying that they are to be executed as a bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Am I missing something or doing it entirely the wrong way?

Comment: What happens when you try to execute your bash script from fish? Do you get an error?

Comment: The `fish` shell would use `set -x PATH $PATH ~/<path>/<to>/<scripts>`, not `export` (it's not really a POSIX shell). But it's not clear where you do that `export` thing to add to the `PATH`.

Comment: Where is the `export PATH=...` line? Is that something you typed into the console or is it in a config file? If so, which config file?

Comment: I made an attempt to create an arrangement in my [dotfiles](https://github.com/myTerminal/dotfiles)  that would work with both *bash* and *fish*, tried to extract as many common elements as possible so that I do not need to configure both separately. The `export` is [here](https://github.com/myTerminal/dotfiles/blob/2b93886b151dcadeb8517271605fe1bda49b1f34/.config/bash/config#L4)

Comment: That file is not valid fish syntax. fish does not claim to be a POSIX compatible shell, it is a different beast. I would not recommend spending any effort trying to find common ground, and put that effort into using fish syntax to configure your fish shell.

Comment: Thanks, @glennjackman. However, even after changing `PATH` the `fish` way, running the script throws an error as `bash` syntax is not identified with `fish`. Isn't the shebang supposed to help?