# I'm not able to figure out why fish-shell is not able to read my scripts directory from $PATH

Tags: path, fish

After [my failed attempt to unify my bash and fish configuration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531761/unable-to-execute-bash-scripts-from-within-fish-shell), I have finally separated both and 'hoping' that things should be fine now.

As per the suggestions I received (against trying to re-use my bash configuration for fish), I did the following:

1. Separated out any common configuration between bash and fish even if it meant duplicating my configuration scripts
2. Altered `$PATH` for fish explicitly, even though it seemed to read the right path as set in bash
3. Defined aliases for fish separately, even though it automatically wrapper all bash aliases as functions and worked like a charm in a few environments

There is still a problem I'm facing: I'm not able to execute my custom scripts from a particular location I added in `$PATH`. I'm sure I'm missing something very basic but am not able to figure out what that is.

Please help!

Comment: There's a lot of ways this sort of thing could go wrong. How did you edit `$PATH`? What does `echo "$PATH"` show? What version of fish are you using? What happens if you try to execute these scripts?

Comment: I modified the $PATH using the line here: https://github.com/myTerminal/dotfiles/blob/e1ca4d306df6ce8a8bbafa35c6cfc910329a84c3/.config/fish/config.fish#L2. `echo $PATH` shows `/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin ~./shell/scripts`, the last path being the one where my scripts reside. My version of fish is 3.0.2. Before I execute those scripts, fish (obviously) doesn't provide its regular completion and after I execute them anyway, it says, "Unknown command <command-name>".

Comment: Ah, the dot in `~./` is pretty weird - it's trying to load the home directory for user `.` which will fail.  Assuming your files are in `~/shell/scripts/`, if you use that path, does it work? (or maybe you wanted `~/.shell/scripts/`?)

Comment: You got it! Thanks :)

Comment: As a side note, the way you set and export `PATH` is a bad idea. It will grow with each spawned instance of the shell. Take a look at the manual.

Comment: @bool3max, thanks for pointing it out. There are cases where a particular path gets repeated. Upon receiving your comment, I did investigate and ran a few experiments with my configuration, breaking it down and trying to add paths to `PATH` in a few different ways and haven't been able to figure out what the issue is. I'm pretty naive at shells but all I could figure out is that the repetition occurs differently depending upon which out of `bash` or `fish` is my default shell, and whether I'm testing it on macOS or Fedora. Any pointers would really help shorten my clueless adventures. :)

Comment: @myTerminal https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_path

Comment: I'll explore that, thanks. I just did [this](https://github.com/myTerminal/dotfiles/commit/a437f437fcbedcaa8700fa9294e2d2429e3b07fd) a few hours back.